# Is $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap L^q(\Omega)$ Uniformly Convex?

Tags: banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain and $p<q$ with $p,q\in (1,\infty)$. Is $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap L^q(\Omega)$ Uniformly Convex with respect to the norm: $\|u\|=\|u\|_{1,p}+\|u\|_q$?

Note: Observe that by an similar argument like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316914/is-w-01-p-omega-cap-l-infty-omega-complete?rq=1), we have that $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap L^q(\Omega)$ is Banach with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|$

Comment: I guess that it should be, because its norm is the sum of two uniformly convex norms.

Comment: That's my guess too @GiuseppeNegro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's equip $W^{1,p}_0\cap L^q$ with the norm $\|\cdot\|_*$ such that 
$$\|u\|_*^2=\|\nabla u\|_{L^p}^2+\|  u\|_{L^q}^2
\tag1$$
Then the map $u\mapsto (\nabla u,u)$ is an isometric embedding of $W^{1,p}_0\cap L^q$ into the direct sum space $L^p\oplus  L^q$ with the $2$-norm. By the latter I mean the norm $\sqrt{\|x\|_X^2+\|y\|_Y^2}$ on the direct sum $X\oplus Y$ of two Banach spaces.

Theorem 5.2.25 in *An introduction to Banach space theory* by Megginson asserts that $X\oplus Y$ is uniformly convex (with the above norm) if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are both uniformly convex. This answers the question.

If one takes for granted the equivalence of

- uniform convexity of $X$
- uniform smoothness of $X^*$
- uniform continuity of the duality map $X^*\to X$ on bounded subsets.

then the statement is transparent: $(X\oplus Y)^*$ is isometric to $X^*\oplus Y^*$ (**only** because we use the $2$-norm), and the duality map on the product is the coordinate-wise combination of duality maps.

Comment: THank you Pavel. Please, let me ask you something. Reflexibility is an property that's depends on the norm? If I have some reflexive space, can I find some norm on it in such a way that it isn't reflexive?

Comment: @Tomás Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic Banach spaces. Take the second adjoint of an isomorphism $T:X\to Y$ to get an isomorphism $T^{\ast\ast}:X^{\ast\ast}\to Y^{\ast\ast}$. By construction we have a commutative square-shaped diagram in which the vertical sides are canonical embeddings $X\to X^{\ast\ast}$ and $Y\to Y^{\ast\ast}$. Now it should be clear that if one of these canonical embeddings is surjective, so is the other. // Conclusion: reflexivity is preserved by isomorphisms.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I understood it. If the norm is equivalently, then the space still reflexive?

Comment: @Tomás Two norms on the same space are equivalent iff the identity map is an isomorphism.

Comment: I see. Did you know examples of reflexives spaces such that, when renormed with a non-equivalently norm it is non-reflexive?

Comment: @Tomás They are not very explicit. For example, the spaces $\ell_2$ and $\ell_1$ are isomorphic as **algebraic** vector spaces: that is, their Hamel bases are of the same cardinality. Such an algebraic isomorphism $T:\ell_2\to\ell_1$ can be used to put the norm $\|Tx\|$ on $\ell_2$, which makes the space isometric to $\ell_1$.